# How to set the borderline according to the image height and width in react native?

Tags: css, react-native

How the image border will be set in UI according to the image height and width. Here I have removed the background color of the selected image to transparent and trying to set the border dotted lines to its width and height.

[image]

[image]
I need to show as the image sandal.

Comment: crop the image, cutting off it's transparent area

Comment: How to crop its area

Comment: I have already set a height and width for that image. Each images are in different sizes. So I have added the image as transparent to see its behind image. But some image filled in the container with no transparent area.

Comment: with an image editor, what did you use to make the transparency?

Comment: I simply set the background color as "transparent" in Animated View style. The image is render by using the FastImage component

Comment: So you want something like this? https://snack.expo.io/@cgomezmendez/nervous-french-fries

Comment: @CristianGomez Yes, I have attached another image in this thread. Reload it to see the image which needs for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If your images don't have the same dimensions, you can't set the same borderline, e.g they can't fill all space.